# How to repair my jupyter notebook/lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I code in jupyter notebook/lab, if I press enter, two new lines will be 
generated, like this: [image]

If I press tab, the code hint appears, but the cursor jump to
the next cell, like this: [image]

These two problem appear recently, I have uninstalled all ipython & jupyter 
and reinstall, change browser from chrome to firefox, even when I code in 
google colaboratory and coursera's deeplearning exercise, except in pycharm.

Comment: Did you pip install jupyter or was it installed through Anaconda?

Comment: Anaconda, conda, these problems still exist in online jupyter notebook(google colaboratory, jupyter's official demo, coursera's exercise) after I uninstall jupyter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a great tool solved these problem partly--[nteract](https://nteract.io/desktop), I can run local jupyter notebook in it, but the online jupyter notebook run in browser remains unnormal.

---

New in April 6, I finally find it! This is caused by a script of tempermonkey, which called remove-web-limits, just disable it and everything OK!